# Use .NET WebForms for project rebuild

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I'm working on a fairly big .NET WebForms application. Now we have to rewrite parts of the application (and over some time the whole thing).

Should we stick around with WebForms or should we use MVC for the newer parts?

Does somebody has information what the plans from Microsoft are with WebForms?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200256/is-asp-net-webforms-swept-under-the-rug-to-make-room-for-mvc

Comment: I was more concerned about the support for the webforms technology in future versions of :NET...

Comment: Those old answers actually tell you all you need to know - web forms won't be going away any time soon.

Comment: Well then there is the question we should...